# Yii 1 CDbHttpSession timeout ignored

Tags: php, yii

Both CDbHttpSession and CHttpSession seem to be ignoring the timeout value and garbage collect data after a fairly short time (less than 12 hours). What could be the problem?

```
    'session' => array(
        'class'=> 'CDbHttpSession',
        'autoCreateSessionTable' => true,
        'autoStart'=>true,
        'timeout' => 1209600,
        'cookieMode' => 'only',
        'sessionName' => 'ssession',
    ),
```

Comment: you are still able to login directly even if 12 hours have passed ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be this is what you are looking for

> Setting the timeout for CHttpSession just sets the
>   session.gc_maxlifetime PHP setting. If you run your application or
>   Debian or Ubuntu, their default PHP has the garbage collector disabled
>   and runs a cron job to clean it up.
>
> In my apps I set the session dir somewhere in protected/runtime to
>   separate my session from other apps. This is important on shared
>   hosting sites and it's a good habbit. The downside is that I have to
>   remember to set up a cronjob to clean the files in that folder.
>
> Anyway, you should also set a timeout when calling CWebUser.login to
>   log in a user.

from [Yii Forum Post](http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/49076-timeout-not-working-for-chttpsession/)

Check `duration` parameter in [CWebUser.login](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CWebUser#login-detail)